# Quickly create a pre-determined filter in gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, google-chrome-extensions

I receive a large number of cold inbound marketing emails. Relatively few offer an unsubscribe link and so I'd like to be able to quickly create a rule to archive/add a tag to all emails from that domain. However, using the "Filter messages like this" wizard is surprisingly involved and time consuming for what it does. Is there any faster way to do this given that I know ahead of time the exact shape of the rule except for the domain?

Comment: Just edit an existing filter using [https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/filters](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/filters) and add the new domain name to the existing filter.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. There may be a rule that prompted you to post this as a comment and not an answer but if it were an answer I would happily accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a filter setup for one domain, you can edit it to include additional domains using `OR`

Example 
`from:(domain1.com OR domain2.com)`

You can quickly access the existing filters in order to edit them using the following URL:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/filters